# Exclude cflags in Android.mk

Tags: android-ndk, android-source

I wish to exclude some global compile flags from my Android.mk compilation e.g. -Werror=format-security. Is there any recommended way to do this without hacking into some central Android make files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least be able to override those settings by adding more cflags within your own Android.mk, by adding e.g. `-Wno-error=format-security`.